# Symbols in Haskell

Tags: haskell, symbols

I have a problem in understanding a symbol in Haskell:

```
=<<
```

as in:

```
-- return the last ten lines of a file
tail10  = drop =<< subtract 10 . length
```

can anyone explain to me what this means?

Also I find this happens alot when I'm studying Haskell is that i bump into one of these symbols I have no idea what they mean or how they work. Is there a site or a tutorial that goes into greater depth concerning only the symbols in Haskell rather than the functions themselves?

Comment: Haskell allows you to define your own infix operators, so you cannot really have an exhaustive list of them somewhere. However, you can try Hoogle - http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3D%3C%3C

Comment: It is just `>>=` with the order of the arguments reversed.

Comment: and in this case, it's in the `(r ->)` function monad which shares an argument across functions, where `>>=` is defined as `(f >>= g) x = g (f x) x`, so the code is equivalent to `tail10 xs = drop ((subtract 10 . length) xs) xs`.

Comment: But in this case, `=<<` = `concatMap`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Here's a list of the reserved keywords in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords). The `=<<` that you're asking about is merely a function, so we can [ask Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28=%3C%3C%29). [It tells us](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3a-61--60--60-) that `=<<` is simply [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3a-62--62--61-) with its arguments reversed. `>>=` is a fundamental monad function ("monadic composition") that you can read about in many places, including [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).

Comment: thank you gspr, this keyword list is exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: When/if hammar writes down his comment as an answer, you really should accept that instead. He actually *answers* what `drop =<< subtract 10 . length` does, which I avoid.

Comment: Maybe "reserved keyword" is not the best characterization of =<<. The Haskell Report, section 2.4 Identifiers and Operators, defines (among other lexemes) "reservedid" (case | class | data [and so on]) and "reservedop" (.. | :: | = [and so on]). >>= and =<< are neither of these. What are they, then? >>= is a method exported from Control.Monad (section 13.1) and =<< is a basic Monad function (section 13.2.2).

Comment: @rickythesk8r: The "these" in my first sentence refers to what the link points to, not to `=<<` and friends. I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: @gspr: My mistake. I misunderstood the original question as -- paraphrasing -- "I don't understand what =<< means and would like to consult a 'keyword list' to find out."